# "Minutes of meeting" or "Minutes meeting"

Tags: expressions

What is the right expression, "minutes of meeting" or "minutes meeting"?

Comment: *Minutes meeting* would imply that the meeting is about the minutes (most likely of another meeting). If you kept a record of this meeting, you would produce *minutes meeting minutes*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either "minutes of the meeting" or "meeting minutes", but not "minutes meeting".

"Meeting minutes" is used a bit more often according to [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minutes%20of%20the%20meeting,meeting%20minutes&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

[image: minutes]

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the record of a meeting, the expression is *minutes of the meeting.*

Comment: Or perhaps the *meeting minutes*.  But not *minutes meeting*.  That would probably mean the length of time (in minutes) that the meeting lasted.  Unless that's what you wanted?

Comment: @GEdgar: ...or a meeting about the particular time period called 'minutes'.